# implementing negamax algorithm with alpha beta pruning for connect four in C

Tags: c, negamax, connect-four

I am currently writing a connect four game in C, and I have already made a working minimax algorithm to find the best move (with a depth of only 12). I recently remembered about negamax, and how it might be faster to run, but when I tried to implement it, the move found was never good.

So far I have tried looking around on the internet and everytime I rewrite the code, I end up rewriting the same function as before, but I really don't understand why it is wrong...
Everything apart for the negamax function works, as it worked perfectly using minimax.

It's also important to note that `PLAYER_X` is 0 and `PLAYER_O` is 1.
The `getScore(PLAYER)` function simply returns a heuristic score for a player.

Here is the minimax function that works fine:

```
int minimax(int depth, int alpha, int beta, int maximizingPlayer) {

    //Only the maximizing player can possibly win, because he played last
    if(isWin(maximizingPlayer))
    {
        return (1-maximizingPlayer)*10000 - maximizingPlayer*10000;
    }

    if(isDraw())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (depth == 0)
    {
        return getScore(maximizingPlayer) - getScore(1-maximizingPlayer);
    }

    int bestValue = 999999;
    if(maximizingPlayer)
    {
        bestValue = -999999;
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++)
    {
        if (isValidMove(col))
        {

            makeMove(col, 1-maximizingPlayer);
            //1-maximizingPlayer inverts who the maximizingPlayer is
            int eval = minimax(depth - 1, alpha, beta, 1-maximizingPlayer);
            undoMove(col, 1-maximizingPlayer);

            if (maximizingPlayer)
            {
                bestValue = (eval > bestValue) ? eval : bestValue;
                alpha = (alpha > eval) ? alpha : eval;
            }
            else
            {
                bestValue = (eval < bestValue) ? eval : bestValue;
                beta = (beta < eval) ? beta : eval;
            }
            if (alpha >= beta)
            { //Pruning
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return bestValue;
}
```

Here is the incorrect negamax function:

```
int negamax(int depth, int alpha, int beta, int maximizingPlayer) {

    if(isWin(maximizingPlayer))
    {
        return 10000;
    }
    if(isWin(1-maximizingPlayer))
    {
        return -10000;
    }

    if(isDraw())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (depth == 0)
    {
        return getScore(maximizingPlayer) - getScore(1-maximizingPlayer);
    }

    int bestScore = -999999;

    for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++)
    {
        if (isValidMove(col))
        {

            makeMove(col, maximizingPlayer);
            int score = -negamax(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha, 1 - maximizingPlayer);
            undoMove(col, maximizingPlayer);

            if(score > bestScore)
            {
                bestScore = score;
            }
            
            if(score > alpha)
            {
                alpha = score;
            }
            //Alpha beta pruning
            if (alpha >= beta)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return bestScore;
}
```

I'm very new to algorithms such as negamax... so any help will be appreciated!

The full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/H2MqLtGf)

An example of it failing is to just play the following sequence: 3, 2, 4 and immediately win.

Another example is to simply play the column 3 four times in a row. It is never blocked, so the player immediately wins.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Note that your post does not contain a question. Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions. You should narrow down the problem as much as possible, at least to a specific situation, and you should provide everything a reader needs to reproduce that situation.

Comment: For negamax, where the current player's best score is the highest value regardless of which side is playing, the `isWin` logic also has to give a maximum (positive) score for the current side winning and a corresponding negative score for the current side losing. Here you hard-code a PLAYER_X win as positive and a PLAYER_O win as negative. The depth==0 logic also needs to have the sign of its result reflected by who is moving, that is, if PLAYER_X's score is greater than PLAYER_Y's but PLAYER_Y is moving, the score must be negative.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've edited the code so the isWin and the depth==0 logics are correct. However I still get the same results. Even just stacking 4 stones in the center column wins...
I've also added the full code to make it easier to reproduce.

Comment: Sorry for being too vague... my question is mostly why does the minimax algorithm work but not the negamax one? Of course the answer to that is the fact that the code is wrong, but I can't see where.

Comment: Since you have a working and a non-working algorithm, you have the opportunity to run them side by side, or to generate extensive logs, and compare them to see where one goes off the rails.

Comment: While this isn't a full answer, it seems I was stupid and forgot about integer overflows. Indeed, doing the negative of INT_MIN does not result in a positive number, but as -2147483648. I've adjusted the code so that this doesn't happen :/